# The [save report to file.vi] in report generation tool always Prompt regardless of whether the file to be saved already exists

Tags: labview

When I was using the report generation tool, I found that when I set the do-or-not prompt replacement in [save Report to file.vi] to true，it still always Prompt regardless of whether the file to be saved already exists.It seems like it creates a temporary file with the same name before saving, so what's the point of this option? And I want to know how to do what it was supposed to do.

[image]

Comment: A quick test here shows that it prompts only when the input is T, so I don't know what's happening in your code. It's easy enough to look inside the VI to see what it's doing, so I suggest you do that. The help says the input is only relevant for HTML, but it's used for Word and Excel as well.